# _SmsMessageTracking coming soon columns

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, data-views

I'm reviewing the [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sms_message_tracking.htm&type=5) relates the _SmsMessageTracking DV and noticed some new columns but it says 'coming soon' , so when this will happen and how this affect existing queries? I see very valuable for example an [status code](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/sms-status-codes.htm) about the SMS delivery

Specifically I'm looking when this will be available to be used...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These fields all appear to be at least partially populated:

```
SELECT
    SMSStandardStatusCodeId,
    count(1) as Sends
FROM 
    _SMSMessageTracking
WHERE
    DATEDIFF(day,CreateDateTime,GETDATE()) < 30 AND
    Outbound = 1
GROUP BY
    SMSStandardStatusCodeId
```

Yields this result:

[image]

Possibly the documentation's now out of date.

Comment: This is great @Macca!, which instance you are using? I couldn't able to get it in my instance.

Comment: This was on s11.

Comment: Oh okay cool. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Also seems to work for s7 and s10 @NaveenVM. Which stack are you using?

Comment: yes mine is also s10. I checked when SFMC release notes came. Now am also getting it. I guess the document is outdated. Thanks for sharing this @Macca.